# Python IRC-Bot Quakenet No Ident Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc

i've got some problems with connecting my Python IRC-Bot to the Quakenet.
Other Networks (like freenode or euirc) are working fine.
Code of my irc-lib: https://github.com/Thor77/PythonIrcBot/blob/master/irc.py
Output of my bot:

```
b'>>PASS somepassword'
b'>>NICK Thor2'
b'>>USER Thor2 Thor2 Thor2 :Thor2'
b'<<NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname\r\n'
b'<<NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking Ident\r\nNOTICE AUTH :*** No ident response\r\nPING :3048259664\r\nNOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname\r\n'
b'<<:protectglobal.uk.quakenet.org 513 Thor2 :Your client may not be compatible with this server.\r\n:protectglobal.uk.quakenet.org 513 Thor2 :Compatible clients are available at ftp://ftp.undernet.org/pub/irc/clients\r\nERROR :Closing Link: Thor2 by protectglobal.uk.quakenet.org (Registration Timeout)\r\n'
```

Comment: This isn't really programming related - at best it's too broad as how you implement an `identd` server for your bot is up to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is,
i needed to respont to a PING,
after the NICK-Message.

```
self._send('PASS somepassword')
    self._send('NICK ' + nick)
    self._read() # reads messages from server, find ping, send pong
    self._send('USER %s %s %s :%s %s' % (nick, nick, nick, nick, nick[::-1]))
```